# HtmlUnit click anchor does not trigger javascript click eventListener

Tags: javascript, html, spring, addeventlistener, htmlunit

I'm trying to programmatically click on an anchor using HtmlUnit. I have following options set.

```
    webClient.options.isThrowExceptionOnScriptError = false
    webClient.options.isThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode = false
    webClient.options.isJavaScriptEnabled = true
```

I fixed all of the js warnings and I see js `console.log()` output in my logs, but not the ones defined in the

```
item.eventListner('click', function() {
    console.log("test")
}
```

So, it seems that the listener does not trigger onClick. Also defining onClick inline with the anchor element produces an output.

```
<a name="word" href="#" onClick="console.log(1);" id=${i++}>$word</a>
```

Comment: Can you please add a sample HtmlÜPage that shows the problem. Do you use the latest HtmlUnit version?.
And pleae open an issue on github - will have a look.
But in general this should work.

Comment: I think the method is named addEventListner() instead of eventListener() or do you use some library?